# Is it possible to resume operation after pausing in jupyter

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to pause the operation of jupyter while performing a computational intense task freeing the cpu and resume it later.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is very outdated, but I found a solution to this problem after searching for quite a while! I actually ended up trying a bunch of random combinations.

CTRL+S worked for me when using jupyter notebook **with Anaconda**.

You must be in the shell for this to work. 
Also, other key combinations that didn't work for me but were suggested elsewhere include: 
CTRL+Z 
and 
CTRL+I

Hopefully this can at least help out someone down the line...

Answer (score 2):

In current Jupyter no such option. But you can try system tools

In case of Task manager in Windows:

1. Identify running process with name python.exe
2. Set low priority of the process with a click in popup menu

For more control try  "[Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer)".
It can Suspend command for the tree of processes.

Also see https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/1spmpt/pause_a_running_python_script_and_resume_when/ for further tricks On Linux or Mac.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that should work on a Mac or Linux (perhaps Winders too, but your mileage may vary).  There should be a terminal window running Jupyter.  Navigate to that terminal window and press Control-Z.  It will suspend the job and put it in the background.

:

:

[I 13:24:05.147 NotebookApp] Saving file at /seisbench/examples/createGEOFON.ipynb

[I 13:25:04.858 NotebookApp] Saving file at /seisbench/examples/createGEOFON.ipynb

^Z

[1]+  Stopped                 jupyter notebook

To restart, type 'fg' in the terminal window to bring the job to the foreground.  You could probably do a 'bg' to put it in the background too, but I did not test this.

(bds) LC02WR133HV2R:notebooks a0194920$ fg

jupyter notebook

[I 13:27:05.231 NotebookApp] Saving file at /seisbench/examples/createGEOFON.ipynb

:

During the time the application was stopped, all the Jupyter notebooks stopped updating.  Once the application was placed back in the foreground, all the Jupyter windows continued where they left off.  Good luck.